# While loop works with the interaction pane, but not exactly

Tags: java, while-loop

This is supposed to take the length of the input number and tell it. I have the print statements for this specific case in the main method, which are at the top of the code, and the actual method code below it.

```
case '1':
            System.out.printf("Enter an int number: %d\n",num);
            num = in.nextInt();
            setLength(num);
            System.out.printf("The length of %d is: %d\n",num, Program8.length);
            break;
...

 public static void setLength (int num) {
      int count = 0;
      while (num!=0) {
         num = num % 10;
         ++count;
      }
      Program8.length = count;
   }
```

When I type one of the test cases, i.e. Program8.setLength(0123400); Program8.length, I get the right number, but not written the right way. I should get:

The length of 0123400 is: 6

Instead, I get

The length of 0is: 66, with the last 6 lit in light blue as if I was initializing a variable. I'm not sure how to get it in the right format.

Comment: A simple typo. You are using the [Modulo (%) Operator](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) instead of the [Division (/) Operator](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/math-operators-and-math-class.html#division). This: `num = num % 10;` should be: `num = num / 10;`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a homework and we do not need to prove our own implementation, then we may solve this with what java has already given us;

```
Program8.length=Integer.toString(num).length();
```

But, if we have to show our own implementation to someone, then this can show what you miss in your implementation, which has already pointed out in the comments above by @DevilsHnd;

```
/*
reportDigits(192837465);
reportDigits(19287465);
reportDigits(1927465);
reportDigits(193765);
reportDigits(37465);
*/    

    void reportDigits(int number) {
        System.out.print(number + " has ");
        int len = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            len++;
            number /= 10;
            //number = ((number - number %10) / 10);
        }
        System.out.println(len + " digit(s)");
    }
```

Comment: thank you @double-beep, i hope i did right this time.